# String initial is an integer

Tags: c++

i have a string and i want to put a check on it's initial if it is an integer value then read it, `str="100 john smith";`
currently i am using this code.

```
if(isdigit(line.substr(0,1))){}
```

But not working. if my integer would be constant then i will be using `line.substr(0,1) == "1"` but my integer could very like 0 to infinite values, but i need to put check i should be an integer not any other line in the file haveing strings.
any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`std::string` overloads the `[]` operator so you can just do:

```
if (isdigit(line[0])) { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

I see what you're trying to do, and it's correct, but there are technicalities you need to know about

You write `line.substr(0,1)` because you want the first character. You get the first character, but you get it in a `string`. To get the first character directly you need to do `line[0]`.

What is the difference? `line.substr(0,1)` happens to return 1 character, but if you did `line.substr(0,2)` then it would return 2 characters. So it has to return something that can hold either 1 or 2 (or more) characters. That something is a `string`. And it returns a `string` *everytime* no matter the input. That's how c++ works - functions always return the same type. If it has to return a string for some inputs, it has to return a string for all of them.

If you want a character, you have to use a function that *can't* return more than 1 character. That, for strings, is either the `at` member function or, more widely used, just using the `[]` opeartor.